# Добавление данных в бд через форму php

Tags: php, sql, база-данных, формы

Проблема: Не получается отправить данные в бд из формы. Есть метод в контроллере который обрабатывает запрос

```
public function addAction() {

        if (!empty($_POST)){
            if (!$this->model->postValidate($_POST,'add')){
                $this->view->message('Ошибка',$this->model->error);
            }
            $this->model->postAdd($_POST);
            $this->view->message('Добавлено','ok');


        }
        $this->view->render('Добавить');
```

В свою очередь он вызывает модель с методом

```
public function postAdd($post) {
        $params = [
            'id' => '',
            'name' => $post['name'],
            'text' => $post['text'],
        ];
        $this->db->query('INSERT INTO posts VALUES (:id, :name, :text)',$params); 
}
```

Валидация формы проход но данные так и не попадают в бд. С подключением проблем нет. Чуйка подсказывает что не правильно состовляю запрос и видимо параметры не правильно передаются. Может подскажите что делается не так?

Comment: `id` - автоинкремент? удалите его, полностью, его не надо заносить, оно само добавиться, автоматически.

Comment: Удалил на данный момент выглядит так: public function postAdd($post) {
        $params = [
            'name' => $post['name'],
            'text' => $post['text'],
        ];
        $this->db->query('INSERT INTO posts VALUES (:name, :text)', $params);

    } Не работает

Answer (score 0):

Выполните sql-запрос (**внимание: удалит вашу существующую таблицу**):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `posts`;
CREATE TABLE `posts` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `text` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Функция добавления:

```
public function postAdd($post) {
    $STMT = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO posts (name, text) VALUES (:name, :text)");
    $STMT->bindParam(':name', $post['name']); //, PDO::PARAM_STR - можно как третий параметр
    $STMT->bindParam(':text', $post['text']);
    $STMT->execute();
}
```

Comment: Если и это не сработает, проверьте а вызывается ли у вас вообще `postAdd()`?